# SettingWithCopyWarning of Pandas

Tags: pandas

I use apply function of pandas:

```
def get_value(x):
    #processing
    return x

df['result'] = df['data'].apply(get_value)

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

How to avoid this warning?

Comment: How to use 'loc' to do it?

Comment: I can only find the solution of "pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None"

Comment: A lot depends on what is going on in get_value(). Just returning x from that function shouldn't throw this working. You could try creating a deep copy with `df['result'] = df['data'].apply(get_value).copy()`